# Calcular la mediana solo si el grupo tiene más de 20 casos

Tags: r, shiny, r-dplyr

```
    tabla %>%
    group_by_at(input$SelectProfesional) %>%
    summarise_at(input$SelectTiempo,median,na.rm=T)
```

Necesito que calcule la mediana pero solo para los profesionales que aparecen mas de 20 veces, es dedir, despues de agrupar por el input profesional, que cuente la cantidad de veces que aparece cada profesional y para los que aparezcan mas de 20 veces, que calcule la mediana.

Comment: ¿Pero que buscas? ¿Que solo se muestren los profesionales con maś de 20 apariciones? ¿o que se muestren todos y la mediana solo en aquellos que tienen más de 20 apariciones?

Comment: que muestre la mediana de los profesionales que aparecen mas de 20 veces

Answer (score 2):

Es mucho más simple calcular la mediana por cada grupo y luego determinar que hacer si el grupo tiene más o menos ocurrencias de las esperadas. Voy a usar `mtcars` y enuncio el mismo problema, calcular solo la mediana de `wt` de los `cyl` que tienen más de 10 filas:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(wt_median = median(wt), n=n()) %>% 
  mutate(wt_median = ifelse(n>10, wt_median, NA))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
    cyl wt_median     n
  <dbl>     <dbl> <int>
1     4      2.2     11
2     6     NA        7
3     8      3.76    14
```

Básicamente calculamos la mediana para todos los grupos y con `n()` obtenemos la cantidad de casos por grupo, finalmente setamos en `NA` la mediana de los grupos con menos ocurrencias de las deseadas.

También si lo que buscas es simplemente, calcular y filtrar puedes hacer:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(wt_median = median(wt), n=n()) %>% 
  filter(n>10)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
    cyl wt_median     n
  <dbl>     <dbl> <int>
1     4      2.2     11
2     8      3.76    14
```